# Error 304 Node/Express

Tags: nodejs, express

Estoy recien empezando con node, creando un localhost en un archivo app.js, donde no se porque cuando voy al explorador en network me indica el error 304. Agrego una imagen para que puedan verlo tambien.
Que puede ser?

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hola mundo');
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
 console.log("Gonzalo el server esta listo en el puerto 3000..");
});
```

[image: Browser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El status 304 no es un error, los errores comienzan desde el status 400 en adelante. Este status te dice que no realizaste nungún cambio en la ventana, entonces el browser puede continuar usando la misma versión almacenada en su caché.

mira este link que te explica todos los status http
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: Muchas gracias!!